# WAL file retention in Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication, aws-aurora

I’m planning to create a bunch of Aurora Postgres clusters with `logical_replication` enabled, so I would not have to reboot my clusters once will need to enable logical_replication for future replications.

Is it possible to configure retention for the WAL files, as it is possible to do so for MySQL binlogs? If not, am I risking my disk space, since the WAL files will grow with no limit? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're planning to enable logical replication now, but create subscriptions later, and worry about WAL file accumulating between now and then.

Aurora, being a managed service, does not expose the `wal_keep_size` (formerly known as `wal_keep_segments`) parameter. It does, however, [expose `max_slot_wal_keep_size`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Reference.ParameterGroups.html), which is apparently what matters to you. With logical replication the WAL retention is managed by the replication slots, so until you create one or more slots, no WAL files will be retained beyond what Aurora itself needs.

Aurora doesn't seem to define any default value for `max_slot_wal_keep_size`, which I take to mean it'll accumulate unread WAL files *in slots* forever, which means you might potentially run out of disk space *if* you create replication slots before activating the subscribers. However, if you create replication slots simultaneously with creating subscriptions, there should be no problem.